# Clear cache tool missing

Tags: cache

I'm trying to clear templates cache. The Craft CMS 3 documentation says:

```
 You can also manually clear all of your template caches from the Settings page, using the “Clear Caches” tool.
```

When I go into Settings, I don't see any options to clear the cache there, nor is it within any of the other options there (General, Sites, Routes, etc). Do I have to enable the utility somehow?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, @JacobWeiss! We’ve updated [the Tags page](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/tags.html#cache) and included a note about the `craft clear-caches` console command.

Comment: I found it, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is out of date.  The cache tools now live under the Utilities section.  Presumably you need admin privileges to see/access/use these tools.

[image]

Comment: Found it, thank you!